# Rails 4 has_many through - Cannot modify association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have DayItem model which has one SchoolProgram which has many seminars.

```
class DayItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :school_program, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :seminars, through: :school_program

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school_program
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seminars, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class SchoolProgram < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :day_item
  has_many :seminars, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seminars, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Seminar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school_program
end
```

I am using cocoon gem for dynamic nested forms as follows.

_form.html.haml:

```
= simple_form_for [@day, @day_item] do |f|
  = f.input :start_time
  = f.simple_fields_for :school_program do |form|
    = form.input :school
    = form.simple_fields_for :seminars do |seminar|
      = render 'seminar_fields', :f => seminar, :parent => form
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add seminar', form, :seminars
```

_seminar_fields.html.haml:

```
.nested-fields.well.well-compact
  .form-inline
    = f.input :name
    = link_to_remove_association "remove seminar", f
```

But when I try to add a seminar I get following exception.

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection in Etm::DayItemsController#update
>
> Cannot modify association 'DayItem#seminars' because the source reflection class 'Seminar' is associated to 'SchoolProgram' via :has_many.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Circular reference in relationships (source reflection)

There may be more than one issue here, but the first one that should be addressed is that your relationship for Seminars creates a circular reference. It is declared in a has_many in DayItem and then as a has_one on SchoolProgram, which itself belongs to the parent class DayItem. Please try the change below to our DayItem model. Leave the other models as they are, and let me know how that goes.

```
class DayItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :school_program, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school_program
end
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. If i remove seminars association, then I get an error so I have to remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for :school_program` and no seminars would be shown

Comment: Oops. Yes. Of course remove the the nested attributes. I edited the answer. Like I mentioned, there may be more than one problem. The model has a circular relationship. That has to be fixed first. Then you can set the other relationships properly. I can help, but will need to see more code. "No seminars are shown" need more details.

Comment: I edited my main question and added more code. By "No seminars are shown"  I mean it gives me an error `Association seminars doesn't exist on DayItem` on line `= link_to_add_association 'add seminar', f, :seminars`

Comment: Yes. The form code needs work. I'll look at look at that now. I use Simple Form, but not Cocoon nor HAML, but I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: I suppose that `link_to_add_association` uses variables from parent form, in this case `= f.simple_fields_for :school_program do |form|`, so I will try to change it to cocoon way too and see if that helps.

Comment: It's not clear that Cocoon will allow more than one level of association nesting. "Nested forms are forms that handle nested models and attributes in one form; e.g. a project with its tasks or an invoice with its line items."  It might be okay, but if I was using this gem, I would post a question to the developer at the repo https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon and make sure that the gem will work for more than one level of nesting.

Comment: It works now. Thanks. I added `:parent => form` to `= render 'seminar_fields', :f => seminar` and changed `= link_to_add_association 'add seminar', f, :seminars` to `= link_to_add_association 'add seminar', form, :seminars`. I corrected it in question.

Comment: Great news! Glad it helped.